# GROK Pattern filtering

Tags: logstash, grok

Hi I am new to logstash and grok filtering, I have a sample log like this:

1/11/2017 12:00:17 AM : 
Error thrown is:
No Error

---

Request sent is:
webMethod:GetOSSUpdatedOrderHeader|appCode:OSS|regionCode:EMEA|orderKeyList:|lastModifedDateTime:1/10/2017 11:59:13 PM|

---

I want to filter out the line separator which is a line full of ** (the last line)
Also when I want to be able to capture entire line including ":" in one field. For example in the above log, `webMethod:GetOSSUpdatedOrderHeader` has to be captured in one field in my grok pattern. Is there a way to achieve this?? TIA. Please refer the attached image for the [sample log message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtvoU.png)

Answer (score 1):

A few tips:

- Photos of logs are not a good way to offer someone an example, copy and paste the log
- The [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) is a great way of building your own grok patterns

This should work for the sample log line you pasted in:

```
%{NOTSPACE:webMethod}\|%{NOTSPACE:appCode}\|%{NOTSPACE:regionCode}\|%{NOTSPACE:orderKeyList}\|%{NOTSPACE:lastModifedDateTime}
```

However, what you requested, probably isn't quite what you want, as you just want the field content in the result, not the name of the field as well. This should give you more sensible results:

```
webMethod:%{NOTSPACE:webMethod}\|appCode:%{NOTSPACE:appCode}\|regionCode:%{NOTSPACE:regionCode}\|orderKeyList:(?:%{NOTSPACE:orderKeyList}|)\|lastModifedDateTime:%{NOTSPACE:lastModifedDateTime}
```

You would then want to process the lastModifedDateTime field with the [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) filter to get the date stamp in a format logstash can save to.

Comment: apologies for the poor way of displaying the logs and thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: 1/11/2017 12:00:17 AM : 
Error thrown is:
No Error
*************************************************************************
Request sent is:
webMethod:GetOSSUpdatedOrderHeader|appCode:OSS|regionCode:EMEA|orderKeyList:|lastModifedDateTime:1/10/2017 11:59:13 PM|
*************************************************************************                          this is the custom log, the stars(*) are not displayed in the question, my grok pattern works fine but captures these stars as well,is there a way I can drop or ignore these?@Rumbles

Comment: Yes there is, but that's a different question

Comment: can you please help me with the syntax? I have tried if condition s and mutate but just could not get it right !

Comment: If you ask a new question I can have a look at it.